# XSLT copy node and alter attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm working with some very large XML files containing logging records. I have multiple XML files with varying parameters, though the `<record>`, `<date>` and `<message>` tag are always present.

They look something like this (very simplified):

data1.xml:

```
<record>
  <date>2018-10-01 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data1</message>
  <param key="Key1">Info</param>
  <param key="Key2">Info</param>
  <param key="Key3">Info</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2018-10-02 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data1</message>
  <param key="Key1">Info</param>
  <param key="Key2">Info</param>
  <param key="Key3">Info</param>
</record>
```

data2.xml:

```
<record>
  <date>2018-10-01 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data2</message>
  <param key="Key4">Info</param>
  <param key="Key5">Info</param>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2018-10-02 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data2</message>
  <param key="Key6">Info</param>
  <param key="Key7">Info</param>
</record>
```

data3.xml:

```
<record>
  <date>2018-10-01 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data3</message>
  <param key="Duration(h)">0:00:10</param>
  <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
</record>
<record>
  <date>2018-10-02 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data3</message>
  <param key="Duration(h)">0:01:30</param>
  <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
</record>
```

I'm using XSLT to filter the records based on a number of variables, i.e. could be date & message,  or message and key1, etc, etc.

Inside of the XSLT , all I need to do is filter out the desired records, and call `<xsl:apply-imports>` to have a chain of other XSLT files that manage things like sorting the output, formatting and other things.

I'm currently filtering out the desired XML nodes as following:

For this example, lets assume I want the records with `<message>data1</message>` and `<message>data3</message>`, and edit their attributes to display them in a table nicely.

filter1.xsl:

```
<!-- ignores records not matched by another template, so in this case 'data2' -->
<xsl:template match="record" /> 

<!-- applies imports to 'wanted' data -->
<xsl:template match="record[message='data1']"> 
  <xsl:apply-imports />
</xsl:template>

<!-- applies imports to 'wanted' data -->
<xsl:template match="record[message='data3']"> 
  <xsl:apply-imports />
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename 'param' to match the attribute from 'data3.xml' -->
<xsl:template match="param[@key='key1']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute>attribute1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

So far so good, now for my question.

Every record in 'data3.xml' marks the end of an operation, hence the 'duration' parameter. I want to duplicate every node to mark the start of this operation.

So for input:

```
<!-- marking end of operation -->
<record>
  <date>2018-10-01 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data3</message>
  <param key="Duration(h)">0:00:10</param>
  <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
</record>
```

I want output:

```
<!-- marking start of operation -->
<record>
  <date>2018-09-30 23:59:50</date>
  <message>data3</message>
  <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
</record>
<!-- marking end of operation -->
<record>
  <date>2018-10-01 00:00:00</date>
  <message>data3</message>
  <param key="Duration(h)">0:00:10</param>
  <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
</record>
```

But I haven't found out how to duplicate an entire node and process both of them. Here's what I've tried so far:

Calling named template to create a new node based on existing nodes attributes, This did not insert any node at all:

```
<xsl:template match="record[message='data3']">
  <xsl:call-template name="duplicateNode"></xsl:call-template>
  <xsl:apply-imports />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="duplicatePrintedNode">
  <xsl:copy>
    <record>
      <date>2018-09-30 23:59:50</date>
      <message>data3</message>
      <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
    </record>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Copy entire node using `<xsl:copy-of value"">`. This seemed to insert a node **inside** an attribute of the existing node I wanted to copy:

```
<xsl:template match="param[@key='Duration(h)']" mode="copy">
  <record>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </record>
</xsl:template>
```

So how can I duplicate a node, change the attributes and then apply templates and imports to both of them?

I've searched on SO and Google a lot but the keyword `copy` seems to have multiple meanings withing the XSLT context. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have `xsl:template match="record[message='Printed']"`, why do you expect that to be applied to an input with `<message>data3</message>`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Oops, I forgot to change that when 'simplifying' my code. Edited.

Comment: This is quite confusing. Do you want to apply imports to both copies of the record? Just one? None? Creating the copy should be quite trivial; computing the starting dateTime far from it.

Comment: I want to apply imports to both copies, because the imports will handle things such as sorting, trimming excess attributes and other things. Calculating the starting time is a whole other issue, that's not my question here.

Comment: This is difficult, because we don't know exactly what the imports do. Judging from the other templates, they also copy the node. So if you copy it yourself, then apply imports, you will end up with 4 records, two nested in other two.

Comment: In this XSLT I need to transform the `<record></record>` end node, to `<record></record><record></record>` start node end node and apply imports. Nothing more, does that clarify anything? I realize it may be confusing,

Comment: Doing exactly what you said would be trivial (I will post an answer shortly). But I still have doubts about the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following (much) simplified example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <record>
        <date>2018-10-01 00:00:00</date>
        <message>data3</message>
        <param key="Duration(h)">0:00:10</param>
        <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
    </record>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record[message='data3']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <date>new value</date>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()[not(self::date or self::param)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <record>
      <date>new value</date>
      <message>data3</message>
      <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
   </record>
   <record>
      <date>2018-10-01 00:00:00</date>
      <message>data3</message>
      <param key="Duration(h)">0:00:10</param>
      <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
   </record>
</output>
```

---

**Note:** For the purpose of this demonstration, I have used `xsl:copy-of` instead of `xsl:apply-imports` - since we don't know what those imports are.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. One question, I'm guessing that `[not(self::date or self::param)]` tells the XSL processor to ignore the `date` attribute of the current node?

Comment: `date` and `param` are *elements*, not *attributes*. But yes, the predicate excludes both of them from being included in the selection.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Well I should be able to solve the problem now. I'll try to refactor my code to implement your solution since its a lot more readable I think. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. In anticipation of your next question, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196330/conver-edt-to-gmt-in-xslt-1-0/46196920#46196920

Comment: Which processor? AFAIK, only libxslt supports `date:add()`.

Comment: I'll have to check, can't find it right now (it's hidden deep inside legacy packages:-)). But I will keep that in mind thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it, I realize that the educational value of this is very slim because my scenario is so specific but I'll post it anyway. Also thanks to @michael.hor257k for trying to help.

The way I duplicated the specific node and applied imports to both is this:

filter1.xsl

```
<!-- ignores records not matched by another template, so in this case 'data2' -->
<xsl:template match="record" /> 

<!-- applies imports to 'wanted' data -->
<xsl:template match="record[message='data1']"> 
  <xsl:apply-imports />
</xsl:template>

<!-- applies imports to 'wanted' data -->
<xsl:template match="record[message='data3']">
  <xsl:call-template name="duplicateNode"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename 'param' to match the attribute from 'data3.xml' -->
<xsl:template match="param[@key='key1']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute>attribute1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- here I edit attributes to my liking, and then simply apply imports again -->
<xsl:template name="duplicateNode">
  <record>
    <date>
      <xsl:value-of select="./date" />
    </date>
    <message>data3 copy</message>
    <attribute1>Info</attribute1>
  </record>
  <xsl:apply-imports />
</xsl:template>
```