# XSL Transformation 1.0 - Minus Hours

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to take off 20 hours from the expectedDispatchDate

Input XML:

`<Extrinsic name="expectedDispatchDate">2020-01-15T16:00:00+01:00</Extrinsic>`

XSLT:

`<xsl:value-of select="Extrinsic[@name='expectedDispatchDate'] - 20"/>`

Output XML:

`2020-01-14T20:00:00+01:00`

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196920/3016153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the EXSLT dates-and-times library at www.exslt.org, and in particular at the XSLT template named `date:add-duration` which can be found at http://exslt.org/date/functions/add-duration/date.add-duration.template.xsl