# Convert Date Time from one time zone to another time zone in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xalan

How can we convert date-time from GMT to EST or another time zone using java's Xalan extension? Currently, I am using apache Xalan.

**Input XML**-

```
<root> 
    <name>
        <CreatedTimestamp>2020-05-26T14:58:57.466</CreatedTimestamp>
    </name>
</root>
```

Can we get XSL which will convert `<CreatedTimestamp>` from GMT to any given time zone?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How will you supply the target timezone? -- Note that this is much easier in XSLT 2.0 (which Xalan does NOT support).

Comment: Date and time handling is one of the major areas where XSLT 2.0 wins heavily over XSLT 1.0. Are you really constrained to use Xalan, which hasn't been upgraded for years?

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Can't we supply target timezone as a param?

Comment: @MichaelKay - can we handle DST as well in xslt 2.0?

Comment: Yes, you can. But in order to provide an answer, we need to know what will be the format of the parameter. If, for example, it will be the offset in hours, then the solution is (relatively) easy. OTOH, if you want to supply it as an IANA time zone (e.g. "America/Panama") then it's not possible in XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0 - but *might* be possible in XSLT 3.0.

Comment: It will be offset in hours. Could you share one sample example that would be helpful?

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196330/conver-edt-to-gmt-in-xslt-1-0/46196920#46196920