# xslt or xquery to add a min to the current time

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xquery

i want to create a security header as below:

```
 <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd xmlns:wsu=http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd>
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-E157FC3B34ADB1C4DF16976549459948">
        <wsu:Created>2023-10-18T18:49:05.994Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2023-10-18T18:50:05.994Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
```

</soapenv:Header>

For `<wsu:Created>2023-10-18T18:49:05.994Z</wsu:Created>`  I want to have current date time and
 `<wsu:Expires>  </wsu:Expires> has to be 1 min more than current time`
is there any function in xslt 1.0 that i can use to have current date time and 1 min more than it or in xquery to

Comment: For XSLT 1.0 see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196920/3016153. Note that some XSLT 1.0 processors support extension functions that can make this much simpler.

Comment: Note also that pure XSLT 1.0 does not have a current date or time functions.

Comment: Thanks. Any way i can havecurrent date time and 1 min more than current date time

Comment: You should be able to pass the current datetime as a parameter to the stylesheet (this depends on the application that calls the XSL transformation). Or perhaps get it from a web service. Then add 1 min as shown in the linked answer. That's the most you can do in pure XSLT 1.0. Again, I suggest you check what extension functions are supported by your processor.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky to achieve in XSLT 1.0, but easy enough in XSLT 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 (which share the same function library). It's simply

```
current-dateTime() + xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1M')
```

Comment: Thank u so much